# Access class members without copying this or mutex variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda, mutex, copy-constructor

I'm trying to create a simple Worker class, which will create a number of threads and a set of tasks for the threads to run. This is educational, but I have already tried asking classmates and searching for different answers, and I think there is something "simple"/fundamental I'm missing here.

I'm having some issues regarding where my mutex variable should be set. I believe I would want one for each of my Worker objects, as the threads created by each object are completely unrelated. Right now, I'm trying to pass `this` to the lambda method that adds to the set of threads, but this copies the mutex, which deletes it. Is there a way to copy each class member I need independently, or should I create a copy constructor? I'm only trying to pass the class variables I need to the lambda. Here is my code:

```
// TDAT2004Task2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class Worker {
    int threads;

    mutable mutex tasks_mutex;

    vector<thread> worker_threads;
    list<function<void()>> tasks;

public:

    Worker(int threadAmount) {
        threads = threadAmount;
    }


    void start() {
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
            //This is the place errors occur. I'm copying the this element, and thus deleting my 
            //mutex variable.
            worker_threads.emplace_back([this] {
                while (true) {
                    function<void()> task;
                    {
                        lock_guard<mutex> lock(tasks_mutex);
                        if (!tasks.empty()) {
                            task = *tasks.begin();
                            tasks.pop_front();
                        }
                    }
                    if (task) {
                        task();
                    }
                }
                });
        }
        for (auto& thread : worker_threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
    }

    void post(function<void()> function) {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(tasks_mutex);
        tasks.emplace_back(function);
    }
};


int main()
{
    //This does not compile. 
    Worker worker_threads = Worker(4);
}
```

My error message in VS:

```
>------ Build All started: Project: TDAT2004Task2, Configuration: x64-Debug ------
  [1/2] C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1424~1.283\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP   /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 /showIncludes /FoTDAT2004Task2\CMakeFiles\TDAT2004Task2.dir\TDAT2004Task2.cpp.obj /FdTDAT2004Task2\CMakeFiles\TDAT2004Task2.dir\ /FS -c ..\..\..\TDAT2004Task2\TDAT2004Task2.cpp
  FAILED: TDAT2004Task2/CMakeFiles/TDAT2004Task2.dir/TDAT2004Task2.cpp.obj 
  C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1424~1.283\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP   /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 /showIncludes /FoTDAT2004Task2\CMakeFiles\TDAT2004Task2.dir\TDAT2004Task2.cpp.obj /FdTDAT2004Task2\CMakeFiles\TDAT2004Task2.dir\ /FS -c ..\..\..\TDAT2004Task2\TDAT2004Task2.cpp
C:\Users\Even\source\repos\TDAT2004Task2\TDAT2004Task2\TDAT2004Task2.cpp(74): error C2280: 'Worker::Worker(const Worker &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
  ..\..\..\TDAT2004Task2\TDAT2004Task2.cpp(69): note: compiler has generated 'Worker::Worker' here
  ..\..\..\TDAT2004Task2\TDAT2004Task2.cpp(69): note: 'Worker::Worker(const Worker &)': function was implicitly deleted because a data member invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex &)'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\mutex(92): note: 'std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex &)': function was explicitly deleted
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Error message from cpp in the console:

```
C:\Users\Even\source\repos\TDAT2004Task2\TDAT2004Task2>gcc TDAT2004Task2.cpp
TDAT2004Task2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
TDAT2004Task2.cpp:74:34: error: use of deleted function 'Worker::Worker(Worker&&)'
  Worker worker_threads = Worker(4);
                                  ^
TDAT2004Task2.cpp:18:7: note: 'Worker::Worker(Worker&&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class Worker {
       ^~~~~~
TDAT2004Task2.cpp:18:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)'
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/mutex:43:0,
                 from TDAT2004Task2.cpp:13:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/bits/std_mutex.h:97:5: note: declared here
     mutex(const mutex&) = delete;
     ^~~~~
```

Thank you for any responses! Please point at any stupid mistakes I've done, I'm just trying to learn the best practices.

Comment: Passing `this` does not copy the object. `this` is a pointer.

Comment: @user253751 I might have thought so. Then why is my mutex variable deleted? When I compile with gcc, I end up with this final error: `mutex(const mutex&) = delete`;

Comment: That does not mean the mutex variable was deleted.

Comment: @mvidelgauz I added the error messages now.

Comment: @user253751 Oh. Do you know what is happening then?

Comment: _"error C2280: 'Worker::Worker(const Worker &)': attempting to reference a deleted function"_ and _"error: use of deleted function 'Worker::Worker(Worker&&)' Worker worker_threads = Worker(4);"_ - both explain why you cant' write like this. In short, you need `Worker worker_threads(4);`

Comment: IMO the diagnostic is wrong here. You provided copy constructor for `Worker`, so you also  should provide move constructor (and assignment operators), as per [the Rule of Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I wouldn't call it _wrong_, it is just too formal. But IMO it isn't compiler primary job to explain about Rule of Five

Comment: @mvidelgauz Yeah, too used to Java. Thank you!

Comment: To instantiate a class use `Worker worker_threads(4);` not `Worker worker_threads = Worker(4);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was, that you defined a copy-constructor. Therefor you do not have a default move contructor.

I do not see how you can have a correct copy-constructor, since `std::thread` can not be copied, therefore a `std::vector<std::thread>` can not be copied.

A default-move-constructor should work for your case.

So to be explicit add the lines:

```
public:

   Worker(const Worker&) = delete;
   Worker& operator=(const Worker&) = delete;
   Worker(Worker&&) = default;
   Worker& operator=(Worker&&) = default;
```

to your Worker class.